Button Widget in Tkinter executing code when not clicked
I was making a basic tkinter program that would change the text of a label.
When the program was run, it already said "You clicked the button!" while the button was not clicked. Note that I did not click it.

Also, I tried using other commands like print("") but the program printed whatever was written automatically at the start of the program.
Here's my code
from tkinter import *

Window = Tk()
Window.title("Button on Click")
Window.geometry("350x350")

Label1 = Label(Window, text="Click the button")
Label1.grid(column=2, row=1)

def Click():
   Label1.configure(text="You clicked the button!")
   Label1.grid(column=2, row=1)

Button1 = Button(Window, text="Surprise!", fg="blue", command=Click())
Button1.grid(column=1, row=1)

Window.mainloop()


you called the command at
Button1 = Button(Window, text="Surprise!", fg="blue", command=Click())

i believe it should be without the brackets
Button1 = Button(Window, text="Surprise!", fg="blue", command=Click)

